# Transimpedance Amplifier with forward biased photodiode

Tags: amplifier

I am working with a kind of a photodiode that detects pulsed light. The problem that I have is that I need to forward bias the photodiode. Unfortunately most TIAs are not made for such high bias currents as I need.

The photodiode is biased with approx. 3V/100mA. The input bias of typical TIAs that I found don't go much above 5mA. One strategy that I tried, was to use a Bias-Tee (such as this: https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=ZX85-12G-S%2B) with a TIA on the AC port and the photodiode on the DC+AC port. It kind of worked, but the results seemed very strange (too small, too noisy and weird dynamics).

Is there some kind of proper DC-block solution for current signals?

Does it make sense to try a simple resistor in series as current-to-voltage converter? With the voltage signal I could have better options to use standard RF components.

Any other thoughts on such a setup?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the diode?  The specifics are going to matter for any TIA.  Forward biasing it will also result in a lot of additional shot noise which will be superimposed on top of the photocurrent, so you will need to consider that as well.

Comment: What's the reason for the forward bias?

Comment: There is no datasheet - it's an experimental device. Thanks for the hint about the shot noise!

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to try a simple resistor in series as current-to-voltage converter?

Yes, at high currents this is acceptable as long as the resistance of this *current-to-voltage converter* is small enough.

The idea of the transimpedance amplifier is more clever - to use a resistor with a relatively high resistance (and accordingly, high voltage drop across it) but to neutralize its resistance (voltage drop) by adding an equivalent voltage (this is the role of the op-amp in this circuit of two elements). As a result, the whole circuit behaves as a "piece of wire" or an "active super-conductor". The problem is that the current enters/exits the output of the op-amp and it has to be able to supply it.

The same problem exists with multimeters in "current measurement" mode. It would be great if this could be done with a transimpedance amplifier; then it would be an "ideal" ammeter. But it is done with a humble resistor acting as a current-to-voltage converter.

Comment: The problem with a resistor (as you say) is it has to be small enough so that the bandwidth is acceptable.  That might mean that the signal is too small to be useful.  (Hence the wide use of TIA's to provide low impedance and high amplification.)  Since the OP doesn't give any quantitative specs it's hard to know if a resistor will work.

Comment: Ok that sounds promising enough for me to give it a shot! 

Could I build a trivial transimpedance amplifier with an individual OpAmp? Are there OpAmps that are sensitive enough and support the required currents?

Comment: @MrA, I can't say if there is an op-amp with a powerful output, but I guess there isn't, and you have to add it. In the 90's I made such a device for the purposes of a curve tracer.